# DIY project, encountering difficulties with solenoids

Tags: solenoid, diy

I'm currently working on a project that is supposed to dispense something out of a container after receiving an input.

I have a solenoid that connects to an interior hatch.  It will open up a hatch once it receives a signal and close it once the desired amount has been dispensed.

There has been some difficulty in getting the solenoid to extend/retract fully.

Could it be that the internal magnet is not strong enough to make it retract fully? It might be a current issue as well, but changing the resistor values does not produce different results.

The solenoid is powered by a 12V battery, and controlled by an Arduino microcontroller. The two are connected as in this circuit:

[image]

I am using a [DSML-1153-12C solenoid.](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/632/delta_electronics_06152020_DSML-1153-1860120.pdf)

Comment: forget the circuit ... test by connecting solenoid directly to battery

Comment: `internal magnet is not strong enough` ... there is no internal magnet

Comment: Well, the solenoid is only driven in one direction (retraction), so if it's not extending and you can confirm that it's off, that's a mechanical problem.


Also, did you account for the fact that solenoids are VERY weak when fully extended? Theres a chart for that in the datasheet.


One final wrinkle. Energizing a solenoid magnetizes the frame a bit, so they tend to "stick" somewhat in the closed position if the extending force is marginal.

Comment: use a motor, or two solenoids

Comment: Your circuit is sound.  Double-check that by shorting the transistor end of the coil to ground -- if the solenoid acts the same, it **is not the circuit**.  If that's the case, then I suggest you migrate the question to engineering.stackexchange.com -- that's a mechanically-oriented group that should be able to help you understand what you need to do to get your stuff working.  If you _do_ migrate the question, don't bother with the schematic -- show them a mechanical sketch and/or a photo of the mechanism, because it's all in the details.

Comment: "A 12v battery" - details please. Depending on the battery it could have significant internal resistance.